# find the value of the unit vector v using dot product equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have  $$1 = \langle ∇f(2,0), v \rangle = cosθ|(1,1)|$$

where

$∇f(2,0)=(1,1)$ and $v$ has to be a unit vector. then we can find that $ θ= \pi/4 $ or $ -\pi/4$

We want to find the vector $v$, it is specified in my book that $v$ has to be either $(1,0)$ for $θ= \pi/4$ or $(0,1)$ for $ -\pi/4$ how was this found and why can't $v$ have any different value? for example $(1,1)$ why is it dependent on the angle.?

Answer (score 0):

The dot product evaluates to v$_x$ + v$_y$ = 1.
Furthermore as v is a unit vector, v$_x^2$ + v$_y^2$ = 1.
Solve for v$_x$ and v$_y$.